# Change the display of ( ) in a - in the glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the glossaries package and when I use `\gls` for the first time it shows "Complete name (acronym)"
How I can change the ( ) with a single - so it prints "Complete name - acronym"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in chapter 13.1 of the (full) user manual. You basically need to pick a style and then redefine the long call for the acronym that is used in that style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newacronym{HTTP}{HTTP}{Hyper Text Transfer Protocol}
\setacronymstyle{short-long}

\renewcommand*{\genacrfullformat}[1]{%
    \glsentrylong{#1}  -- \acronymfont{\glsentryshort{#1}}%
}%

\begin{document}
A foo walks into a bar. The bartender says have you seen my \gls{HTTP}, foo ? 
\end{document}
```